# ERROR in image preview in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Am using following code to display images in `input box` it works fine, i use single input box to upload multiple using `multiple` and works fine

I need to upload only 5 images so i use `break` statement to stop uploading process if its more than 5 images

### CODE

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
                var files = evt.target.files;
                for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
                    if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                        return function(e) {
                            var span = document.createElement('span');
                            span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                                '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                            document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
                        };
                    })(f);
                    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

the above code display image preview

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2z45bew/)

### ERROR

- if user add more than 5 images **i need to display only 5 images**
- if i select 3 images for first time and in same input box if i select 5 images these 5 images and first 3 images are displayed but the first 3 images are not uploaded **so i need to display only images in peer list**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a length AND i<5 in the loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i<files.length && i<5; i++) {
    var f = files[i];
```

If you think the file type will be an issue, you can always have a second counter in play

```
var imgCount = 0;
for (var i = 0; i<files.length && imgCount<5; i++) {
   var f = files[i];
   if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
       continue;
   }
   imgCount++;
```

And for your other issue, uou need to clear the output area when you start to add images.

```
document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = "";
for (var i = 0; i<files.length && i<5; i++) {
    var f = files[i];
```

---

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;
    var listOut = document.getElementById('list');
    listOut.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length && i < 5; i++) {
        var f = files[i];
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
            return function (e) {
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.className = "thumb";
                img.src = e.target.result;
                img.title = theFile.name;
                span.appendChild(img);
                listOut.appendChild(span);
            };
        })(f);
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Comment: where to ad length i tried`f = files[4];` how to clear output are if user clicks add images ??

Comment: can you please help me how do i clear output if user add images second time

Comment: i don't find any error and i don't get preview can you please add full code( modify my question and post as answer)

Comment: Ah, you are using insertBefore and that does not add it to the element.

Comment: so what's the solution??..sir

Comment: Append the elements inside the output and not as a sibling of that element. http://jsfiddle.net/a10mybzz/